# how do I determine if a number is in the middle half cantor set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ D $ be the "middle half" Cantor set of all $ x ∈ [0, 1] $ having a representation in the form
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {a_i}/{4^i}
$$

where each $ a_i $ is either 0 or 3.

How do I determine if an arbitrary $x$ is in $D$? Using a quaternary representation, $1/4$ becomes 0.1 so the process doesn't seem to be as straight forward as the middle third set where an arbitrary $x$ is in the set if the ternary expansion contains only 0's and 2's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing down the quaternary representation works, if only you remember to rewrite a final `1` as `033333...`.

Comment: is it correct to say let $d$ be in $D$ with quaternary expansion $d=0.d_1 d_2 d_3...$ then $ d_(odd) $ (ie $d_1 , d_3$ etc) must not be 2? @henning

Comment: @user3450230: I'm not sure what that means.